# Replace a capture group with the output from a script

Tags: linux, string, bash, sed

I'm trying to replace all the numbers in a certain text with its full written word form.

For example, if the input is

```
this university has 9123 students
one of its departments has 2315 students
```

The output would be

```
this university has nine thousand one hundred and twenty three students
one of its departments has two thousand three hundred and fifteen students
```

I have a script called `num2words.sh` that can convert a number like 9123 to its word form. I want to use this script to substitute all the numbers in a file called `file1.txt`. I've been trying to use sed but I can't get it to work. So far I have this,

```
cat file1.txt | sed -e "s/\([0-9]\+\)/)/$(./num2words.sh \1)"
```

I guess the **\1** is not being passed correctly. Can anyone provide a solution for this? Using `sed` would be preferable but I'm open to solutions with `awk` and `perl` as well.

Comment: `$()` is replaced when the command line is parsed, not internally by `sed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With perl,

```
perl -pe 's#[0-9]+#`./num2words.sh $&`#eg' file1.txt
```

Comment: Though I'd rewrite the script in perl to avoid having to execute a program for each match.

Comment: I'm getting an error which starts with `Backticks found where operator expected at -e line 1, at end of line` when I run this command

Comment: I solved the above error using `perl -pe 's/([0-9]+)/\`\.\/num2words.sh $&\`/eg'`

Comment: @qk2905 The / in the script path was confusing things; my bad. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's#[0-9]+#$(./num2words.sh &)#g;T;s/.*/echo "&"/e' file
```

Put numbers into `$(./num2words.sh x)` where `x` is a number.

Bail out if no substitution.

Put the whole line double quotes and then echo it out using the `e` flag to evaluate the pattern space.

N.B. There maybe unwanted side effects.